# Linking JS message loop to HTML header

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have been trying to make a loop of messages that change every hour (One is visible at a time) I'm decent at HTML, but I'm pretty bad at JS.  (Message should go in h3)

I tried to link my JS loop into a HTML text element, but I failed.

```js
h3 = document.createElement("h3");
var messages = "Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3", "Message 4", "Message 5", "Message 6";
var counter = 0;

function myLoop() {
  setTimeout(myLoop, 3, 600, 000);
  document.getElementById("Message")
  document.body.appendChild(h3);
}
myLoop();
```

```html
<h3>
  <h3 id="Message"></h3>
</h3>
```

Comment: How exactly have you failed? Is there an error message? How is the result different than expected? `messages` is not a valid variable; is this supposed to be a string or an array or...?

Comment: this code snippet has a lot of syntax errors; please fix them to match exactly what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

1. do not wrap headers in headers
2. It looks like you wanted an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) of messages. I show you below how to make such a thing
3. You would not need to use appendChild when the element already exists on the page
4. `3,600,000` is not valid milliseconds. Use `3600000` or `60*60*1000`

In my code below I use an [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to wait with the execution until the html elements on the page are available

The statement `(counter++)%len` will start at 0 and wrap at length of array of messages using the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator `%`. It saves an `if (counter=> length) counter = 0;`

The `=>` is an [Arrow_functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) making the construct

```
const functionName (parameter) => { };
```

functionally equivalent (there are a few other things) to

```
function functionName(parameter) { };
```

Change the 2000 to 3600000 if you need every hour

```js
const messages = ["Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3", "Message 4", "Message 5", "Message 6"];
const len = messages.length;
let counter = 0;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when the page has loaded and the h3 is available
  const h3 = document.getElementById("Message");
  const myLoop = () => h3.textContent = messages[(counter++) % len]; // loop and wrap
  myLoop(); // run once immediately
  setInterval(myLoop, 2000); // then run every 2 seconds
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h3 id="Message"></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: this is my first interaction with JS, so I'm bad at it. I tried to find some older projects on stack overflow, and combine them. (as you can see, that did not go too well). I tried your version, but I still can't get it to work, since no messages appear. I know this is probably an error on my part, but can you help me to get it working fully?

Comment: I updated the code to start running when the page is running and to show the first message immediately

Comment: I have added more comments to give you the background for my changes

Answer (score 0):

Use this soulution if you want to have different time intervals between messages, but if you are fine with same repeated interval he solution above is more of "best practice".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h3 id="Message"></h3>
    <script>
        var h3elem = document.getElementById('Message');
        h3elem.innerHTML = "Starting text"
        function myLoop() {
            let messages = ['Message 1', 'Message 2', 'Message 3', 'Message 4', 'Message 5', 'Message 6'];
            let timeouts = [1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 6000, 7000];
            for (let i = 0; i< messages.length; i++) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    h3elem.innerHTML = messages[i]
                    console.log("timeout", i)
                }, timeouts[i])
      
            }
        }
        myLoop();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Btw, while investigating this, I was down on my knees, when found out that it will work with `let i = 0` and will not with `var i = 0`.
here is the explanation why https://medium.com/@axionoso/watch-out-when-using-settimeout-in-for-loop-js-75a047e27a5f.

Comment: Thanks! I have 3 questions: 1. If I want to change my intervals to 10 mins, how would I do that ? 2. The messages stop at 6, how can I get them to loop back? 3. Can I randomize the order of the messages?

Comment: **1.**  I would change the `timeouts[i]`, to `timeouts * 600000`. 600000 is 10minutes in milliseconds. So when iterating you will have 1 * 600000 = 10 minutes. 2 * 600000 = 20 minutes. 3 * 600000 = 30 minutes. Thus you will have a message each 10 minutes.\
**2.** If you want to loop back you need another cycle, which is looping backwards. Relace: `for (let i = messages.length; i> 0; i--)`\
**3.** You can change the order manually in `messages` array. Or instead of `h3elem.innerHTML = messages[i]` you can use `h3elem.innerHTML = messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*messages.length)];`

Comment: What do you mean "beginner friendly? You have set up a timeout for EVERY message. That is teaching poor coding to a beginner. That is beginner UNFRIENDLY. I will comment my code better because it is using the current best practices but is indeed more tricky than OP expected

Comment: @mplungjan "beginner friendly", meant using more low level constructions to build the function. I have used seTimeOut, because it was originally used in the question, however I agree that using setInterval is better if you want to invoke something in same time intervals, however it looked like different time intervals was needed here and setTimeOut was used in the initial code, so just worked with this and make the code work.

Comment: _I have been trying to make a loop of messages that change every hour () (One is visible at a time)_ - `3,600,000`

Comment: Also you ran into the let vs var issue, which should be a warning not to do that in a "beginner friendly" example ;)

Comment: You are right, I will edit that my solution is useful when you need different time gaps between messages, otherwise yours is better. Could you please elaborate more on why is it bad to use several setTimeOuts?